# lottery insertion sort algorithm

Tags: python, sorting, insertion-sort

in my lottery game i need to create 1000 players and each player has a number set which needs to be compared with a winning number set. all the numbers sets are from a barrel of 0-30 numbers. this part i have done but now i need to sort the players numbers in to two groups called PWN and SWN. the PWN are the first 6 numbers and the SWN are the last two numbers. Im need to use insertion sort to sort the PWN and Selection sort to sort the SWN. i have still not attended the SWN part as im still stuck trying to figure out the PWN sorting.

```
for example my program create something like below
Winning number 
19, 27, 23, 18, 1, 3, 2, 24

Player ID | Player Numbers
 1        | 8, 14, 3, 4, 10, 21, 2, 22
 2        | 13, 22, 9, 11, 23, 29, 16, 27
 3        | 10, 25, 22, 26, 8, 5, 23, 18

but I need to sort them like 
Winning number 

    PWN                |    SWN
19, 27, 23, 18, 1, 3   |   2, 24

Player ID | Player Numbers PWN        | Player Numbers SWN
 1        | 8, 14, 3, 4, 10, 21       |  2, 22
 2        | 13, 22, 9, 11, 23, 29     |  16, 27
 3        | 10, 25, 22, 26, 8, 5      |  23, 18
```

```
import random

#main code to generate data in the program starts here
def generateRandomNumber():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0,30) #can return numbers between 0 and 30 including 0 and 30
    return randomNumber#return Random numbers

def drawWinningLotteryNumber():#this function generates the winning numbers
    lotteryDrawNumbers = []#list containner for the generated lottery numbers
    for currentLotteryNumber in range(8):#for loop to keep generating for 8 counts
        randomNumber = generateRandomNumber()# call funtion to generate random numbers
        lotteryDrawNumbers.append(randomNumber)# add to the back of the list

    return lotteryDrawNumbers#return the list
    
def printWinningLotteryNumber(lotteryDrawNumbers):#ths function prints the winning numbers
    for currentLotteryNumberIndex in range (len(lotteryDrawNumbers)):#for loop to run the print funtion for the length of the list
        print(lotteryDrawNumbers[currentLotteryNumberIndex], end = " ")#prints the numbers

def draw():# this funtion brings to gether the draw funtion and prints it
    
    lotteryNumbers = drawWinningLotteryNumber()#call function to draw winning numbers
    print ("The 8 lottery number for today are :")
    printWinningLotteryNumber(lotteryNumbers)#call funtion to print the generated numbers

def generateID():#this function creates the lotto players and their numbers
    players = {}

    for player_id in range(1, 1001):
        player_list = []
        for i in range(8):
            player_list.append(generateRandomNumber())
        players[player_id] = player_list

    for player_id in players:
        print("Player {} has numbers {}".format(player_id, players[player_id]))
    pwnSort(players)
    
#data generating code ends here
def pwnSort(players):
    

    for i in range(1, len(players)): 
  
        key = players[i] 
  
       
        j = i-1
        while j >=0 and key < players[j] : 
                players[j+1] = players[j] 
                j -= 1
        players[j+1] = key 

generateID()

draw()
```

when i run this code it creates the data and gets stuck and gives out the following at the pwnSort()

```
Player 984 has numbers [14, 8, 16, 9, 29, 21, 3, 9]
Player 985 has numbers [28, 15, 1, 19, 30, 23, 29, 2]
Player 986 has numbers [6, 8, 13, 0, 19, 5, 13, 2]
Player 987 has numbers [29, 13, 9, 16, 28, 8, 15, 20]
Player 988 has numbers [6, 0, 13, 20, 18, 26, 22, 15]
Player 989 has numbers [29, 13, 17, 16, 18, 13, 14, 8]
Player 990 has numbers [12, 22, 29, 5, 13, 16, 16, 23]
Player 991 has numbers [18, 0, 12, 11, 11, 6, 19, 24]
Player 992 has numbers [4, 0, 19, 24, 17, 20, 19, 3]
Player 993 has numbers [24, 28, 10, 4, 8, 13, 19, 6]
Player 994 has numbers [19, 17, 10, 14, 7, 15, 14, 6]
Player 995 has numbers [1, 18, 24, 5, 29, 19, 20, 2]
Player 996 has numbers [26, 9, 0, 28, 7, 2, 18, 20]
Player 997 has numbers [19, 8, 8, 30, 14, 0, 5, 8]
Player 998 has numbers [19, 16, 7, 14, 16, 25, 0, 21]
Player 999 has numbers [15, 27, 29, 10, 4, 28, 12, 30]
Player 1000 has numbers [8, 18, 6, 6, 17, 25, 6, 16]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/ACBT/Data Sturctures/assignment.py", line 83, in <module>
    generateID()
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/ACBT/Data Sturctures/assignment.py", line 37, in generateID
    pwnSort(players)
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/ACBT/Data Sturctures/assignment.py", line 49, in pwnSort
    while j >=0 and key < players[j] :
KeyError: 0
```

can i know why and how to fix this

Comment: Maybe if the problem is solved with my solution is better to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the conditin of the `while` loop inside the `pwnSort` method.

The condition for the loop is `j >= 0 and key < players[j]` but you are declaring `j = i-1` so at the first iteration the value of `j` will be `0`. Inside your `players` dictionary there is no Key named `0` as pointed out by the error `KeyError: 0`.

To fix this just change the condition as: `j > 0 and key < players[j]`

The final function will result as this:

```
def pwnSort(players):
    for i in range(1, len(players)): 
        key = players[i] 

        j = i-1
        while j > 0 and key < players[j]:
            players[j+1] = players[j] 
            j -= 1
        players[j+1] = key
```